# Laravel relationship - many comments on one post and one user on one comment

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a Post model:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

and every comment has user_id row

I want to get the user with every comment, with relations.

My comments method in Post model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

what is the best approach to get the user with comment?

final result:

```
{ 
  'id': 1,
  'title': 'some title',
  'caption': 'some caption:,
  'comments': [
    { 
      'id': 1,
      'text': 'some text',
      'user_id': 1,
      'user': { 'id':1, 'username': 'something', 'email': 'some@email.com } 
    }, 
    { 
      'id': 2,
      'text': 'some text',
      'user_id': 2,
      'user': { 'id':2, 'username': 'something', 'email': 'some2@email.com } 
    }, 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: do you have the relationship setup on comment to user?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `with()` to the model relation

should be like this

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->with('user');
}
```

please change the user to your model relation

I hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your query by

```
$posts = Post::with('comments.users')->get();
```